# Can we assign signal handler to every signal in linux user space program?

Tags: c, linux

If we assign different handler to say SIGABRT, etc.. We might not be able to kill the process, conspicuously, it's not a good idea unless we can. So, the manual says SIGSTOP and SIGKILL cannot be blocked or ignored, does it mean that it must kill or stop the process no matter what handler you assign?

Comment: @Kevin Can you back that up with a demonstration? As far as I can tell, the manual is correct. `SIGSTOP` can't be handled. It'll stop the process, always. It's a lesser-known rule than the one about `SIGKILL`, but it's true.

Comment: Wumpus is correct.  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigpause.html says that SIGSTOP and SIGKILL cannot be blocked.  A side note: the names of signals are not necessarily portable between UNIXes, and some architectures have different sort of odd signals like SIGPOWER. So be sure to get your list of signals correct for the Os you use.

Comment: @jimmcnamara Sorry still haven't get it clear, does it mean that is impossible for us to use sigaction to define a handler for SIGSTOP and SIGKILL(which is implied by "cannot be caught")?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley So, shall we say like this: the process terminates directly if we send them SIGSTOP or SIGKILL, we are impossible to assign any handler to them, even if the handler will terminate the process in the end?

Comment: Can somebody add their answer to the answer section, so I can choose an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SIGSTOP` and `SIGKILL` signals cannot be caught or ignored. It is possible to set handlers for them using `signal()` or `sigaction()`, but those handlers will never be called, so there is no point in doing so.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to know